# How to add cpp files to Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to add Beecrypt library to my project. First i have added header files but after attempting to create an object i'm receiving the following errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall beecrypt::security::SecureRandom::~SecureRandom(void)" (__imp_??1SecureRandom@security@beecrypt@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
```

As far as i understand it is due to the absence of cpp files. Ok. Then i'm trying to add cpp files but whatever folder i put them i still receive the same error. For example SecureRandom.h is situated:

```
beecrypt/c++/security/SecureRandom.h
```

Where should i put SecureRandom.cpp to get rid of that error? I've already tried all levels of folders. Or maybe that error is caused by something else? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Could you add the complete error message? Usually the message tells which symbol it thinks is missing.

Comment: Don't arbitrarily add .cpp files when you get a linker error from a library.  You'll just dig yourself a deeper hole.  Tell the linker to link the import library, Linker + Input, Additional Dependencies setting.

Comment: Hans Passant Did i understand you right? I don't have to put the files (no matter h or cpp  ) to the project's folder but may just link them to the project somehow by means of IDE?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: If the linking errors you are getting are for a library function that you are using then don't add source files for the libray.Libraries are linked to the code so just need to link the appropriate library to your project.A simple search on google about how to do that will give you step by step procedure.My answer below was posted before you edited the q to say that it is a library linking error.

Comment: It wants the compiled binaries, not the `.cpp` files.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to Just drag and drop them to your project in the solutions explorer.
Or
Follow the steps given in the link below on MSDN website:

**[Adding a Source File.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235632%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Comment: I'm probably stupid but simple search on google gave me nothing. Let me describe the situation fully: there is a folder named Beecrypt with folders containing different (java, python,c++) files.  I CAN NOT add it to the project, there's no such a function in VC2008. So i have to add it file by file. The problem is complicated by two factors: h files referencing each other not just like #include "File.h" but #include "folder1/folder2/File.h", so i have to make a really sophisticated construction to make files see each other. But that's not all. That library (Beecrypt) referncing one more

Comment: library (ICU), so i have to put ICU's h files to the project too. And after i've done all this tremendous work (three hours) i have to add cpp files somehow. You say i may just link it. But how do i link a FOLDER WITH FOLDERS INSIDE IT where h file in one of the folders referencing ANOTHER library? So i just put to the project's folder. h files are seen, cpp are not, this is what i've got.